# Deleting oldest 404 redirects task stalling

Tags: 404, tasks

I have a site which has 100's of pending "Deleting oldest 404 redirects" tasks and they keep stalling so the list isn't clearing.

The client has added lots of custom rules to the `.htaccess` which I will need to investigate, could this be the cause?

Is there a way I can remove all the pending/stalled tasks manually?

Answer (score 1):

I found the table 'craft_tasks' in the database, there were actually over 5,000 tasks in here all run by Sprout Seo. I emptied the table which has cleared the tasks.

I will need to look into why these tasks are not running correctly on the clients server.

Comment: You can use this to help debug stalled tasks: https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks